# Cannot Get Gigabit Connection with BCM57780 and tg3.ko

Tags: broadcom, ethernet

I've got a Broadcom BCM57780 NetLink ethernet adapter in a laptop and I cannot get it to achieve a 1000MBps connection. I have already verified that the cables are good -- other systems work fine using the same cables and switch. I have tried both with and without NetworkManager managing the connection. I have tried to use `ethtool -r` to force renegotiation with and without TSO enabled. In all cases, the BCM57780 always connects at 100MBps/FullDuplex. I have also tried the stock 3.2 kernel as well as the xorg-edgers' 3.5 and the mainline 3.6. None works at gigabit speed.

```
# dmesg | grep tg3
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.6.0-999-generic root=UUID=eccabacd-efb2-45b4-b7a6-2f530d50afd3 ro rootflags=subvol=@ tg3_debug=1 i915_enable_rc6=7 i915_enable_fbc=1 lvds_downclock=1
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.6.0-999-generic root=UUID=eccabacd-efb2-45b4-b7a6-2f530d50afd3 ro rootflags=subvol=@ tg3_debug=1 i915_enable_rc6=7 i915_enable_fbc=1 lvds_downclock=1
[    6.239945] tg3.c:v3.125 (September 26, 2012)
[    6.262748] libphy: tg3 mdio bus: probed
[    6.273209] tg3 0000:01:00.0 eth0: Tigon3 [partno(BCM57780) rev 57780001] (PCI Express) MAC address dc:0e:a1:ac:38:d5
[    6.273220] tg3 0000:01:00.0 eth0: attached PHY driver [Broadcom BCM57780] (mii_bus:phy_addr=100:01)
[    6.273227] tg3 0000:01:00.0 eth0: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[0] TSOcap[1]
[    6.273233] tg3 0000:01:00.0 eth0: dma_rwctrl[76180000] dma_mask[64-bit]
[ 1222.710339] tg3 0000:01:00.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[ 1223.045554] tg3 0000:01:00.0 eth0: Link is down
[ 1237.040178] tg3 0000:01:00.0 eth0: Link is up at 100 Mbps, full duplex
[ 1237.040187] tg3 0000:01:00.0 eth0: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
```

Googling has shown that for a number of non-Ubuntu distros, it may be necessary to load the broadcom.ko module before the tg3.ko module https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/BCM57780. With the above mentioned kernels, however, there is no `broadcom.ko` module.

WTF might be necessary to restore gigabit capability to this NIC?

Answer (score 2):

According to the broadcom devs on kernel.org, Acer intentionally failed to connect all the physical layer pins, leaving the gigabit chip restricted to 100Mbps. Don't you love defective by design hardware.